# How do I add an AVPlayer to a QWidget?

Tags: macos, cocoa, qt4, avplayer, qt4.8

On Mac, I want to use AVPlayer to play video in my Qt 4.8 application since it has features that `Phonon::VideoPlayer` doesn't have.

How do I add the AVPlayerLayer to a `QWidget` so it becomes visible? I'm doing the following:

```
    pimpl->player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFile]];
    pimpl->player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause;
    pimpl->player.rate = 0;

    pimpl->playerLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:pimpl->player] retain];
    [pimpl->playerLayer setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, rect().width(), rect().height())];

    NSView* view = (NSView*)winId();
    [[view layer] addSublayer:pimpl->playerLayer];
```

When I play my video, I hear it, but I don't see it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using winId(), use QMacCocoaViewContainer, but QMacCocoaViewContainer has a bug which will cause the NSView to not be displayed in Qt 4.8 unless setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow); is set.

As well, the NSView may not have a layer, so a layer need to be created.

```
    [pimpl->view setWantsLayer:YES];
    [pimpl->view makeBackingLayer];
```

So in total it looks like:

```
    pimpl->view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
    [pimpl->view setHidden:NO];
    [pimpl->view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [pimpl->view setWantsLayer:YES];
    [pimpl->view makeBackingLayer];

    viewFrame = new QMacCocoaViewContainer(NULL, this);
    viewFrame->setGeometry(rect());
    viewFrame->setVisible(true);
    viewFrame->setCocoaView(pimpl->view);

    NSString* videoFile = [NSString stringWithCString:filename.toUtf8().data() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    pimpl->player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFile]];
    pimpl->player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause;
    pimpl->player.rate = 0;

    pimpl->playerLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:pimpl->player] retain];
    [pimpl->playerLayer setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
    [pimpl->playerLayer setHidden: NO];

    CALayer* layer = [pimpl->view layer];
    [layer addSublayer:pimpl->playerLayer];
```